# How do you create a dart parent to a constant class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a const Obeject to be used as a Flutter theme.  The object needs to be const in order to allow Hot Reload to display changes dynamically.

I've tried various combinations of static const properties and final instance properties but can't obtain the desired effect.

The below does not compile:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ThemeBase globalTheme;

abstract class ThemeBase {
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;

  const ThemeBase();
}

class PurpleTheme extends ThemeBase {
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;

  const PurpleTheme() :
        primaryColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        secondaryColor = Colors.black45;
}

class RedTheme extends ThemeBase {
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;

  const RedTheme() :
        primaryColor = Colors.redAccent,
        secondaryColor = Colors.black45;
}

const Color kAppBarColor = globalTheme.primaryColor;
```

Ultimately the "globalTheme" object would be instantiated in the main.dart for the specific build flavor, or could be used to switch between light/dark theme or to allow user selectable themes - in theory I could just make the properties non-final, but besides losing hot Reload, that would also have a performance penalty.

Comment: You should instead use InheritedWidgets

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I understand that inheritedWidget would just give me a different way of making the "globalTheme" available throughout the app, eg in stead of using a global instance.

Comment: Yes. But they are compatible with hot-reload and are easily overridable. InheritedWidgets were invented for scenarios like theme.

Comment: I used an InheritedWidget to propagate my custom theming and now I have a working DarkMode and a working ThemeEditor.  The issue is that it adds a lot of boiler-plate and overhead, especially with stateless Widgets that needs to obtain the "Theme Data" on every build, or else needs to have it passed down from parent.